# Define permission dont work in lifeary 7.1

Tags: liferay

Hi have 2 entity and 1 portlet:

Entity 1: Autore
Entity 2: Opera
Portlet: BibliotecaWebPortlet

I have create a default.xml for the portlet in resource>resource-action :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE resource-action-mapping PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Resource Action Mapping 7.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-resource-action-mapping_7_1_0.dtd">
<resource-action-mapping>
<portlet-resource>
    <portlet-name>it_cloudtec_biblioteca_portlet_BibliotecaWebPortlet</portlet-name>
    <permissions>
        <supports>
            <action-key>AGGIUNGI_AL_TEMPLATE</action-key>
            <action-key>CONFIGURAZIONE</action-key>
            <action-key>VISUALIZZA</action-key>
        </supports>
        <site-member-defaults>
           <action-key>VISUALIZZA</action-key>
        </site-member-defaults>
        <guest-defaults>
           <action-key>VISUALIZZA</action-key>
        </guest-defaults>
        <guest-unsupported>
            <action-key>AGGIUNGI_AL_TEMPLATE</action-key>
            <action-key>CONFIGURAZIONE</action-key>
        </guest-unsupported>
    </permissions>
</portlet-resource>
</resource-action-mapping>
```

(Portlet name is correct)

i  have created default.xml for service in resource>resource-action:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE resource-action-mapping PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Resource Action Mapping 7.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-resource-action-mapping_7_1_0.dtd">
<resource-action-mapping><model-resource>
    <model-name>it.cloudtec.biblioteca</model-name>
    <portlet-ref>
         <portlet-name>it_cloudtec_biblioteca_portlet_BibliotecaWebPortlet</portlet-name>
    </portlet-ref>
    <root>true</root>
    <weight>1</weight>
    <permissions>
        <supports>
        <action-key>AGGIUNGI</action-key>
        </supports>
        <site-member-defaults>
        </site-member-defaults>
        <guest-defaults />
        <guest-unsupported>
        </guest-unsupported>
    </permissions>
</model-resource><model-resource>
    <model-name>it.cloudtec.biblioteca.model.Autore</model-name>
    <portlet-ref>
       <portlet-name>it_cloudtec_biblioteca_portlet_BibliotecaWebPortlet</portlet-name>
    </portlet-ref>
    <weight>2</weight>
    <permissions>
        <supports>
            <action-key>AGGIUNGI_AUTORE</action-key>
            <action-key>CANCELLA_AUTORE</action-key>
            <action-key>AGGIORNA_AUTORE</action-key>
            <action-key>VISUALIZZA_LISTA_AUTORI</action-key>
        </supports>
        <site-member-defaults>
             <action-key>VISUALIZZA_LISTA_AUTORI</action-key>
        </site-member-defaults>
        <guest-defaults>
            <action-key>VISUALIZZA_LISTA_AUTORI</action-key>
        </guest-defaults>
        <guest-unsupported>
        <action-key>AGGIUNGI_AUTORE</action-key>
            <action-key>CANCELLA_AUTORE</action-key>
            <action-key>AGGIORNA_AUTORE</action-key>

        </guest-unsupported>
    </permissions>
</model-resource>
</resource-action-mapping>
```

Why dont show the action key in control panel? (Website > user > role s > select my custom role > define permission > site administration > application >BibliotecaWebApp)

​​​​​​​I view only default's keys.  > Add to Page - Configuration - Permissions - Preferences portlet.properties is present in portlet and service modules.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/is-cross-posting-wrong-to-an-external-site/141824#

Comment: Please see the link above, decide on which of your crossposts you'd like to have some answer, and link all of the crossposts to each other to make sure that no duplicate work is done on either of the crossposts.